# When /usr is at 100% usage, what can I clean up?

Tags: centos, disk-space

Our web server is showing 100% usage for our /usr partition. I've cleaned the logs, which cleared almost nothing. What else can I remove?

Comment: you can move some of the data to another server, that would be healthy and probably a more long-term solution.

Comment: The logs are probably in /var/log, and not in /usr. (And free space might not have been released unless you either restarted to sighupped the logging proceses). Instead look what you have in /usr/local/. That should be safe to move.

Comment: Yea, /usr/local is 6.6 gigs, but what is safe to remove in there? I've already removed domlogs, but not sure what else I can pull without causing an issue.

Comment: Can you show the output of `cd /usr ; du -s *`?

Comment: Largest is local at 6.6 gigs, second is share at 593 megs

Comment: Since this is a web server with cPanel on it, you would probably do better to ask on a cPanel related forum.

Comment: Things in `/usr` are usually user (well, root) installed as opposed to OS defaults. We cannot know what you can remove because we do not know what you have installed. You need to find what is taking up all the space. `du -ch` and `baobab` (if you have access to GUI tools) are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation (which is not usually required for operation) exists under `/usr/share/doc`, `/usr/share/info`, and `/usr/share/man`.

Comment: All of those are minimal, very little space, about 210 megs together.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/tmp might also be a candidate.....